# Replace implementation of a "sealed" class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

`A` is a class from a referenced dll and thus cannot be changed. It has a method `Foo()` that is called inside my `DoFoo()` method (taking `A` as a parameter). I want to test `DoFoo()` without executing `Foo()` because it's expensive and already tested.

What's best practice to do in such a situation?

My thoughts on this:

- Create a wrapper class around `A` and pass it into `DoFoo()`. The wrapper class distinguishes between the real and the fake implementation.
- The same could be done using extension methods.
- Use `dynamic` and pass in a fake class with an empty `DoFoo()` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Create an interface that contains the methods you want to expose.

Create a wrapper class that implements that interface and which uses the external assembly's classes to do its work. You can create other implementations of this interface, like a mock implementation.

Inject the interface with constructor injection for example, into the classes where you need the functionality.

In your test you can then easily replace the implementation that uses the external library with your mock implementation.

Comment: What's the interface for? Just a wrapper class that could either go the real way or just do nothing would be enough, right? Is there an advantage I've missed?

Comment: Interface based programming in order to be able to reduce dependencies. Real implementation is injected through constructor injection. So yes, I recommend to use interfaces.

Comment: Too old answer but I think it could use some code/pseudocode to explain the point.

Comment: ^ same; please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's very easy doing it with [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com), you wont need to use wrapper or create interfaces, you can just mock it. For example:

method under test:

```
public string DoFoo(A a)
    {
        string result = a.Foo();
        return result;
    }
}

sealed public class A
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var a = Isolate.Fake.Instance<A>(Members.CallOriginal);

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => a.Foo()).WillReturn("TestWorked");

    var classUnderTest = new Class1();
    var result = classUnderTest.DoFoo(a);

    Assert.AreEqual("TestWorked", result);
}
```

Comment: link is broken, It points to http://www.typemCOk.com/ instead of http://www.typemock.com/

Comment: Looks nice, I'd be interested in how they do this. But I don't think I will go with a commercial solution.